# Azure Front Door and DNS Configuration

Tags: azure, dns, azure-front-door

I'm having issue configuring my DNS to make all traffic routed from the root domain (no www) to the Azure front door. The below is what I have done so far:

- Create the front door (frontend/backend/routing)
- On-Board my custom domain (let's say `hello.com`) on front door

Now as per Microsoft guide I have to add a CNAME record to the DNS hosting provider (domain.com) to route the traffic to front door. But I have been told by domain.com that I cannot have A record and CNAME record named `@`

So I've found  this solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/frontdoor/front-door-how-to-onboard-apex-domain

Then I have created a DNS Zone on my Azure environment named "hello.com" and followed the guide.

Still I cannot see the traffic going through the front door.

Is that because I have 2 DNS servers? (one hosted on domain.com and another one on Azure)?

Can It be propagation time ?

Also how does azure know that I'm the owner of `hello.com` domain ?

Comment: It maybe a propogation problem. Wait 4 hours and try again.

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji thanks for your message. do I need to do something else ? ( I now got domain.com domain server and azure domain servers). Is that ok?

Comment: 1) There is no propagation in the DNS and 2) about "Is that because I have 2 DNS servers? (one hosted on domain.com and another one on Azure)?" while not 100% clear you still need to decide on who is your DNS provider and then use only its nameservers with your domain, nothing else. You can not randomly assemble a set of nameservers owned by different companies and expect your domain to work. All of your nameservers should be under control of a single entity (for configuration purposes, security/performances is another problem here).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have updated the domain.com name server to point to Azure DNS Zone.
On Azure DNS there is a A (alias) record to point to the front door. I guess once I have the front door I want the A record pointing to the front door and not anymore to the web app server IP address. is my assumption right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the linking document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/frontdoor/front-door-how-to-onboard-apex-domain), to onboard a root or apex domain on your Front Door, you could use alias records in Azure DNS.

> There are other DNS providers as well that support CNAME flattening or
> DNS chasing, however, Azure Front Door recommends using Azure DNS for
> its customers for hosting their domains.

If you select to use Azure DNS to host DNS domains, first you need to create an Azure DNS zone (hello.com) in Azure and [delegate the domain to Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns#delegate-the-domain) via changing the name server records for the domain in your original DNS registrar. You can verify the delegation by using a tool such as `nslookup` to query the Start of Authority (SOA) record for your zone.  It can take up to 72 hours to propagate worldwide, although it typically takes a few hours.

Then, you can add an alias record for the zone apex in the DNS configuration for the domain to be onboarded. After this, you can add the apex domain name in the `custom host name` field on the Front Door designer tab.

To access your backend web app with the custom domain, ensure that you have created **appropriate routing rules** for your apex domain or added the domain to **existing routing rules**. Or, you may enable HTTPS on your custom domain.